# Асинхронный HTTP сервер или зачем нужен метод HttpListener.GetContextAsync()

Tags: c#, async-await

Есть задача написать простой HTTP сервер. Все примеры, которые мне встречались выглядели как-то так:

```
while (true)
{
    var context == listener.GetContext();
    Task.run(() => HandleContext(context));
   }
```

Ну, ok, но зачем тогда нужен HTTPListener.GetContextAsync();?
Допустим если бы это было так:

```
while (true)
{
    var context = await listener.GetContextAsins();
    Task.run(() => HandleContext(context));
   }
```

Однако, насколько я могу судить, это тоже самое. Буду очень благодарен за пояснение каким образом стоит использовать этот метод чтобы получить какой-то профит.

Comment: Подозреваю, он нужен затем, чтобы его можно было `await`нуть изнутри таска.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это обёртка над вызовами **BeginGetContext** / **EndGetContext**.
Они служат для доступа к асинхронному API, позволяющему использовать I/O Completion Port'ы.

**Вот здесь немножко подноготной:**
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4577193/using-httpapi-with-i-o-completion-ports

Если очень грубо, то это средства операционной системы, которые позволяют не удерживать рабочий поток в ожидании запроса клиента / ответа сервера и т.д.
Если ты запустишь 10 000 параллельных вызовов GetContext() они породят 10 000 висящих в ожидании потоков. В случае использования Async I/O, дополнительные потоки будут порождаться только в момент получения ответа от удалённой стороны, что существенно облегчит жизнь высоко нагруженному серверу.

Comment: Спасибо, но вот что хотелось бы уточнить: Я правильно понимаю, что в цикле должна вызываться
функция в которой уже в свою очередь будет вызываться GetContextAsync()? И еще, GetContextAsync более всего актуален для высоко нагруженных серверов, а если не предполагается, что сервер будет очень уж нагружен, в таком случае нет смысла её использовать? Точнее не так, есть ли смысл её не использовать? То есть, лучше всегда асинхронные методы использовать поумолчанию или в каких-то случаях это может быть нежелательно или даже вредно?

Comment: В примере, который ты привёл, используется конструкция await, которая назначает последующий код в качестве продолжения. Таким образом ты избавляешься от необходимости ручного управления callback'ами. Поэтому, да, оба твоих примера верны. Если бы ты построил вызовы на основе Begin/End, то в обработчике ты бы вызывал вначале End, а затем сразу же Begin, чтобы ещё до того, как ты обработал текущий вызов сервер начал слушать следующий.

Естественно, любые асинхронные вызовы вносят overhead. Но синхронный сервер подвержен различным атакам, в том числе DoS.